# Reading specific characters from a file

Tags: c++11, fstream

I need to "decode" a message from a file by reading the file and storing the cipher into an array. For instance: 
A = Z

B = Y

C = X

D = W

E = V

F = U

G = T

H = S

I = R

J = Q

K = P

L = O

M = N

N = M

O = L

P = K

Q = J

R = I

S = H

T = G

U = F

V = E

W = D

X = C

Y = B

Z = A

2

SLD NZMB KILTIZNNVIH WLVH RG GZPV GL XSZMTV Z ORTSG YFOY? // **Message**

MLMV, GSZG’H Z SZIWDZIV KILYOVN // **Message**

I need to switch the letters in the messages as it is instructed, and I am trying to store the letters into two different arrays. My issue comes when I use getline() and it jumps/skips the first line. Thus, my array instead of being from A to Z, it is B to Z. Meaning that it is storing the first line into my variable Line, but when I want to store it into my array it will start on the second line. Any suggestions? 
PD: the number 2 is the number of messages, meaning that there are two messages that need decoding.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct messages{
int messageNum;
string codeMessage;
string decodeMessase;


};

int main() {

ifstream readMessage;
string line;
int counting = 1;
string code_array[26];
string decode_array[26];
char data;

readMessage.open("input1.txt");
 if (readMessage.fail()){
     cerr << "File input unable to open"<< endl;
     exit(1);
 }

while (getline(readMessage,line) && counting < 26){

   readMessage >> code_array[counting]>> data >> 
 decode_array[counting];
   counting++;
  }

cout.width(17);
cout << "Code array is: ";
for (int i = 0; i <26 ; ++i) {
    cout <<code_array[i];

}
cout << endl;
cout << "Decode_array is: ";
for (int j = 0; j <26 ; ++j) {
    cout << decode_array[j];

}
cout << endl;





readMessage.close();



return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, I would suggest to check your input file. I suspect perhaps a move from a UNIX system to windows may have altered the \n\r\ endings and therefore the library is missing the first line due to this. To troubleshoot, I would TYPE not copy the input to a file and try again. Otherwise, your code appears to not be the issue at first glance.